# Setting python class instance default variables from JSON file

Tags: python, json, class

Looking for an more elegant (and therefore) more robust way of doing this.   Currently I have a class that has some default instance variables defined when it is created.   I then read in a JSON file that allows the user to override some of these defaults.
All of this code is in the **init** method of the class.

```
# Instance variables defaults 
self._a = 'A - original'
self._b = 'B - original'
self._c = 'C - original'

# line below gives example of dict that gets returned from the JSON read
JSON_dict = {'a': "A-overide", 'c': "C-overide"}

# Inelegent code:
if "a" in JSON_dict:
    self._a = JSON_dict['a']
if "b" in JSON_dict:
    self._b = JSON_dict['b']
if "c" in JSON_dict:
    self._c = JSON_dict['c']
```

The structure does not scale well.   Any suggestions on how I can get the desired result in a more Pythonic way?

Not all variables need to be present in the dict from the JSON, but if they are they should overwrite the card coded ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def __init__(self, ...):
  for key, val in JSON_dict.iteritems():
    setattr(self, '_%s' % (key,), val)
```

Comment: Answer works... one clarification: why use (key,).  know it evaluates to tuple, but as fas as I can see it still works if only doing: setattr(self, '_%s' % key, val)     Am I missing something?

Comment: Force of habit. Since you're certain `key` can never be a tuple, it is safe to use `key` alone.